# How to level Maven dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have tried to add a library ([odata4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.odata4j/odata4j-dist/0.7.0)) in Android Studio 1.1.0.

I used the Project Structure:

[image]

When Gradle started to sync, it gave me this error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Nestor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.1.2/eclipselink-2.1.2.jar
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > org.odata4j:odata4j-dist:0.7.0 > org.odata4j:odata4j-core:0.7.0
```

So, to take care of it, I searched for *eclipselink* in the library dependency selector:

[image]

After I added it, Gradle could sync but on compile, I get another error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing org/eclipse/persistence/internal/indirection/jdk8/IndirectCollectionsProvider.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

It seems, *eclipselink* uses Java 8 so it can't work together with my Java 7 Android application.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: just back track among older versions of that artifact for "eclipse.persistence"  like "2.0.0" or something

Comment: @RobertRowntree What do you mean by back track? I can't choose which version to install, the Library Dependency shows only version 2.6.0.

Comment: then transitively speaking, walk back up the dependency hierarchy and select an older version. OR try using "provided" as you see here : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseLoginUI/build.gradle

Comment: @RobertRowntree If I set it to _Provided_, I get the first error of not founding _eclipselink_